# Weak Pointer is nil in block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management, block

I am creating a weakself just right above my block

```
 __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:10.0]
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError ){
                                           NSArray *array = weakSelf.myArray;
                                           NSError *error;
```

}

In side the block the weakself is nil and every property related to weakself is also nil.

Can some tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing 'wrong' as such. The object pointed to by `self` has been deallocated (and thus the reference is `nil`).

Remember that the proximity of 2 pieces of code does not equate to the proximity of the time at which they will run when you are using asynchronous callbacks.

You need to check why the instance is being deallocated when you don't expect it to be (you could implement `dealloc` and add a breakpoint there).

Comment: Also it's necessary to protect variable during execution of the _completionHandler_ block from to became `nil` unexpectedly! You should use _strong_ pointer inside the block. Add `__strong typeof (self) strongSelf = weakSelf;` to the beginning of the _completionHandler_ block then `strongSelf` will be valid till end of block execution.

Comment: @IvanRublev: Not necessarily. In the code shown, it just calls a method once on `weakSelf`. There is no difference between using `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` in this case.

Comment: @newacct agree with you in this case it's not necessary. Because obtained array is pointed strongly.